# Zoomlevel in qml map using osm plugin

Tags: qt, qml

I have a qml map that uses osm plugin and it is in offline mode. I noticed that the maximum zoomlevel is 19 and I want to increase it. How can I change the maximum zoomlevel using this plugin?
Is there a solution?

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtLocation 5.11
import QtPositioning 5.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480


Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"

        PluginParameter {
            name: "osm.mapping.custom.host"
            value: "file:///home/mahmud/Maps/humanitarian/"    // this is the directory of map tiles 
        }
        PluginParameter {
            name: "osm.mapping.providersrepository.disabled"
            value: true
        }
}
Map {
    id: map
    anchors.fill: parent
    width: parent.width
    height:parent.height
    plugin: mapPlugin
    center: QtPositioning.coordinate(32.4279, 53.6880) // Oslo
    zoomLevel: 6
    maximumZoomLevel: 30
    onZoomLevelChanged: {
        console.log(map.zoomLevel)

    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        for( var i_type in supportedMapTypes ) {
            if( supportedMapTypes[i_type].name.localeCompare( "Custom URL Map" ) === 0 ) {
                 activeMapType = supportedMapTypes[i_type]
             }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: please provide [mcve]

Comment: this the qml file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EdpCVKBBztTHhpt_Wbz0VKA-3lbYZ7fL/view?usp=sharing . the offline plugin can be changed

Comment: please add your code inside the post, not as external link.